# How to detect a sudden change in a time series plot in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to "detect" a sudden drop in velocity in a series and I'm not sure how to capture it. The details and code are below:

This is a snippet of the Series that I have along with the code to produce it:

```
velocity_df.velocity.car1

Index   velocity
200     17.9941
201     17.9941
202     18.4031
203     18.4031
```

Here is a plot of the entire series [image]

I'm trying to detect the sudden drop from 220 to 230-40 and save that out as a Series that looks like this:

```
Index   velocity
220      14.927
221      14.927
222      14.927
223      14.927
224      14.518
225      14.518
226     16.1538
227     12.2687
228     9.20155
229     6.33885
230     4.49854
```

I'm just trying to capture an approximate range when there is a sudden decrease in speed so as to use other features.

If I can add any additional information, please let me know. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would be a simple approach, if you want to compare two values one by one:

Given the series from your question, called `s` you can construct the absolute discrete derivative of your data by subtracting it with a shift of 1:

```
d = pd.Series(s.values[1:] - s.values[:-1], index=s.index[:-1]).abs()
```

If you now take the maximum `m` of that series of absolute differences, you can multiply it with a factor `a` between 0 and 1 as a threshold:

```
a = .7
m = d.max()
print(d > m * a)
```

The last line outputs the indices of the matches.

Building up on this, you could use a sliding window technique such as [kernel density estimation, or Parzen window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) to create more smooth results:

```
r = d.rolling(3, min_periods=1, win_type='parzen').sum()
n = r.max()
```

Like before we can print out the matching elements

```
print(r > n * a)
```

Which gives the following output

```
Index
220    False
221    False
222    False
223    False
224    False
225    False
226    False
227     True
228     True
229     True
dtype: bool
```