# How to detect peaks in timeseries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

[slow growing peak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGhkg.png)

How  can we find the sudden peak around index marked as yellow using pandas, I have seen an answer for sudden drops,([How to detect a sudden change in a time series plot in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048291/how-to-detect-a-sudden-change-in-a-time-series-plot-in-pandas))
but i cannot i achieve the sudden peak (yellow point in graph) and slowly growing trend in timeseries in rolling window fashion
if there is a slow growing peak again, how can we detect all points like this in a rolling fashion

Comment: I would  use the sudden drop answer and put a minus sign in front of you data XD XD

Comment: thank you, but i didn't get minus in front of data means?

Comment: Well, if you want to find a peak in your array `data_y`, it is the same as looking for a drop in `-data_y` :)

Comment: can you give us some date to work with?

Comment: Can you please define, what is sudden peak with you as well?

Comment: dec 10 20:20   .12107
dec 10 20:30    .121237
dec 10 20:40   .123112
dec 10 21:30    .12467
dec 10 21:40    .1310
dec 10 21:50    .1350

Comment: The yellow point in the graph, slowing growing overtime

Comment: looking for drop in -data_y didnt help

Comment: @coco18 you could use the same data as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048291/how-to-detect-a-sudden-change-in-a-time-series-plot-in-pandas
i want to detect the change in graph around the index 160

Answer (score 0):

you can use `diff()` and the docs are [hier](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

```
n = 0
m = 1
df.loc[df['velocity'].diff(m)>n]
```

`n` shows the increase of the value, when `n` positive is. `m` is the period.
For user defined changes in the value the both values `n` and `m` have to be adjusted, because the data is not available at the time.

Comment: no, this doesn't give an exact point where there is a sudden change, the point around index 160 is the point where the graph started increasing